# iText: split a PDF into several PDF (1 per page)

Tags: java, itext

What I want is that: given a 10-pages-pdf-file, I want to display each page of that pdf inside a table on the web. What is the best way to achieve this? I guess one way is to split this 10-pages-pdf-file into 10 1-pages pdf, and programmatically display each pdf onto a row of a table. Can I do this with iText? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 15):

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfReader;

public class SplitPDFFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String inFile = args[0].toLowerCase();
            System.out.println ("Reading " + inFile);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
            int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            System.out.println ("Number of pages : " + n);
            int i = 0;            
            while ( i < n ) {
                String outFile = inFile.substring(0, inFile.indexOf(".pdf")) 
                    + "-" + String.format("%03d", i + 1) + ".pdf"; 
                System.out.println ("Writing " + outFile);
                Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
                document.open();
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
                writer.addPage(page);
                document.close();
                writer.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        /* example : 
            java SplitPDFFile d:\temp\x\tx.pdf
            
            Reading d:\temp\x\tx.pdf
            Number of pages : 3
            Writing d:\temp\x\tx-001.pdf
            Writing d:\temp\x\tx-002.pdf
            Writing d:\temp\x\tx-003.pdf
         */
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Stefan actually put up the link with the exact content. So I will accept his answer. +1

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the memory so that actual files aren't made? I would like to loop over all pages and send each one to a OCR for reading text.

Comment: @Omnipresent Yes, there is. Use ByteArrayOutputStream instead of FileOutputStream in PdfCopy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

With `PDDocument` you can do so very easily.

You just have to use a Java List of `PDDocumen`t type and `Splitter` function to split a document.

```
List<PDDocument> Pages=new ArrayList<PDDocument>();
PDDocument.load(filePath);
try {
    Splitter splitter = new Splitter(); 
    Pages = splitter.split(document);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // print reason and line number where error exist
}
```

Comment: The question is about solutions using iText. If you really want to add a solution using a different pdf library, you should at least mention that. Furthermore, this answer essentially duplicates your other answer to this question.

Comment: Yes I mentioned already if you want to look at . I had already mentioned that things can be implemented using PDDocument. I don't understand what you are trying to say. And about duplicate answer I tried to correct previous one.

Comment: *"I had already mentioned that things can be implemented using PDDocument"* - yes. But not everyone knows that that class is part of a different library, PDFBox, and search for that class in itext (as the questionis about itext).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but this line in the most voted answer

```
Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
```

should be

```
Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(i+1));
```

to get the correct pdf size if other pages have different page size (it know it's rare)

Answer (score 0):

I created this method to work with byte[].
It receives a byte array (obtained from a file in the filesystem or a decoded base64 string) and produces a list of byte[] for other operations.

```
private static List<byte[]> splitPdf(final byte[] pdf) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    final var pdfList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    final var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    final var numberOfPages = pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int currentPage = 1; currentPage <= numberOfPages; currentPage++) {
        try (var byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
            var document = new Document(pdfReader.getPageSizeWithRotation(currentPage));
            var pdfCopy = new PdfCopy(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
            document.open();
            pdfCopy.addPage(pdfCopy.getImportedPage(pdfReader, currentPage));
            document.close();
            pdfCopy.close();
            pdfList.add(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());
        }
    }
    return pdfList;
}
```