# itext Split PDF Vertically

Tags: pdf, split, itext

I have requirement where I have to split a PDF page right at center vertically.
I searched through various posts and could not identify the right way to do it

I want to use iText Library using Java.

I used the SplitPDFFile.java from

[iText: split a PDF into several PDF (1 per page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736675/itext-split-a-pdf-into-several-pdf-1-per-page)

and modified it like below, but page not getting split but it copies entire page.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfCopy;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;

    public class SplitPDFFile {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            try {
                String inFile = "C:/input.pdf";

               System.out.println ("Reading " + inFile);
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
                Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(1);            
                Rectangle  psize = reader.getPageSize(1);
                cropBox.setRight(psize.getWidth()/2);
                System.out.println(psize.getWidth());
                System.out.println(psize.getHeight());
                int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                System.out.println ("Number of pages : " + n);
                int i = 0;
                while ( i < n ) {
                    String outFile = inFile.substring(0, inFile.indexOf(".pdf"))
                        + "-" + String.format("%03d", i + 1) + ".pdf";
                    System.out.println ("Writing " + outFile);
                    Document document = new Document(cropBox);
                    PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(outFile));
                    writer.setCropBoxSize(cropBox); 
                    document.open();
                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, ++i);
                    writer.addPage(page);
                    document.close();
                    writer.close();                     
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }   
    }
```

Comment: The original requirement is to split Single page at center vertically and copy LHS in to first page and RHS in to 2nd page and save to output file.

Comment: `PdfCopy` is used to copy pages *as they are* to the new PDF, i.e. the most common PDF merging use case. Thus, your setting a cropbox beforehand is ignored.

Comment: Is there a working code to accomplish the split?

Comment: By *split a PDF page right at center vertically* do you mean splitting along a vertical line, i.e. into the left and the right half? Or do you mean the vertical extent has to be split, i.e. into the bottom and the top half? And does page rotation matter?

Comment: I mean Split one page in to two halves and LHS should be 1st page and RHS should be 2nd page.The input PDF may contain more than 1 page and same should happen in all the pages and I require new PDF out put with pages rearranged as said earlier.

Comment: After searching internet for quite some time finally I found a free tool called Briss. It requires some manual work and I get the required output file now but I want to have my own code rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method using `PdfCopy`, intermittently manipulating the `PdfReader` copied from:

```
void splitIntoHalfPages(InputStream source, File target) throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    final PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);

    try (   OutputStream targetStream = new FileOutputStream(target)    )
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, targetStream);
        document.open();

        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); page++)
        {
            PdfDictionary pageN = reader.getPageN(page);
            Rectangle cropBox = reader.getCropBox(page);
            PdfArray leftBox = new PdfArray(new float[]{cropBox.getLeft(), cropBox.getBottom(), (cropBox.getLeft() + cropBox.getRight()) / 2.0f, cropBox.getTop()});
            PdfArray rightBox = new PdfArray(new float[]{(cropBox.getLeft() + cropBox.getRight()) / 2.0f, cropBox.getBottom(), cropBox.getRight(), cropBox.getTop()});

            PdfImportedPage importedPage = copy.getImportedPage(reader, page);
            pageN.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, leftBox);
            copy.addPage(importedPage);
            pageN.put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rightBox);
            copy.addPage(importedPage);
        }

        document.close();
    }
    finally
    {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

*([SplitIntoHalfPages.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/merge/SplitIntoHalfPages.java))*

This methods creates a copy of the source document containing each page twice, once with the **CropBox** limited to the left half page, once to the right one.

***Beware:*** This method only splits the page **content**. If your source PDFs have **annotations**, you might want to also process them.

Comment: Thank you very much mkl, your code perfectly splitting in two parts and joining them back as I wished to do, I have only content in my input file so annotations and other embedded objects are of no concern to me.

Comment: @mkl Any thoughts on how to process annotations and other embedded objects in this context?

Comment: @Shiran Concerning the annotations I would first try to manipulate the **Annots** array of `pageN` like the **CropBox** above, i.e. first retrieve the original annotations of the page and create two arrays, one for each half page with only the annotations of that half page, then replace the `pageN` **Annots** entry accordingly before adding each half page. If that does not work (I have not tried that yet), I'd instead try and post-process the generated PDF using a `PdfReader`/`PdfStamper` pair and remove off-page annotations. And concerning *other embedded objects* - which do you mean?

Comment: @mkl. Could you please provide an example of how to do it.

Comment: @ShiranSEkanayake Please make that a stack overflow question in its own right in which you **(A)** also provide a representative PDF for your requirements to test against, **(B)** define how how want annotations partly present on both half pages to be dealt with, and **(C)** explain what you mean by *"other embedded objects"*.