# Changing PDF crop/media box using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to to change the media/crop box of an existing PDF using the code below.

```
Document document = new Document();
FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);
PdfCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, outputStream);
document.Open();
foreach (string inFile in inFiles)
{
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inFile);
     float height = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(388);
     float width = Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(176);
     Rectangle newMedia = new Rectangle(height, width);
     copy.AddDocument(reader, new List<int> { 1 });
     copy.SetBoxSize("crop", newMedia);
     reader.Close();
}
document.Close();
```

I am not able to set the media box. It always come back with the same value. Anything that I am missing?

Comment: If you need to change the media box during `PdfCopy`, you can do it similar to how it's done in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32520218/1729265).

Answer (score 2):

Each document has a page tree. This is a structure with `/Pages` dictionaries as branches and `/Page` dictionaries as leaves. Every *page dictionary* (every leaf in the page tree) corresponds with a page.

Each page dictionary has its own `/MediaBox` entry (it's a *required* entry). It can also have a `/CropBox` entry (optional, just like `ArtBox`, `/BleedBox` and `/TrimBox`). These entries can be inherited, so you could add them to a branch (a `/Pages` object to which the `/Page` belongs), but chances are that each page in your existing PDF has its own `/MediaBox` which will overrule the `/MediaBox` defined at the branch level.

Hence, I fear that you'll have to change your code as shown in the [CropPages](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=231) example from my book:

```
public byte[] ManipulatePdf(byte[] src) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
  PdfDictionary pageDict;
  PdfRectangle rect = new PdfRectangle(55, 76, 560, 816);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    pageDict = reader.GetPageN(i);
    pageDict.Put(PdfName.CROPBOX, rect);
  }
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
    }
    return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

In other words: you have to loop over all the pages available through `PdfReader` and change the `/CropBox` (or `/MediaBox`) entry of every page dictionary.